# Count of checkboxes is not showing properly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an app in which i am using in the form of checkboxes. i want to show count of checkboxes in text label i am trying but could not find possible solution.. here is my project link https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu8fdz4y0ps4xye/checkboxwithTableview%202.zip?dl=0 kindly review it.. 
Below is my sample code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[TablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    cell.lblImage.layer.cornerRadius=3.0f;
    cell.lblImage.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;


    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       // [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        //[cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    cell.buttonCheckbox.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.buttonCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    cell.lblText.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblvie];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblvie indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];


    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        self.titleLabel.text=@"";

           }
    else {
        [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSArray *arr=[self.tblvie indexPathsForSelectedRows];// here i am declaring an array but array is coming nil

                self.titleLabel.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    [self.tblvie reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

Comment: I tried your code, when I click on checkbox it is showing checkbox number 1, 2... etc.
What exactly you want to show ? Total number of checkboxes checked ?

Comment: yeah total number of checkboxes checked...

Comment: There are two ways, either get all checkboxes & check which one is checked than show total to label. Costly.
Else simple one, take int count, when checkbox is checked in method checkButton add +1 on uncheck do -1.
in the end show total in label.

Comment: how will you please provide some stuff for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Int variable in .h     `int checkBoxesCount;`
Initialize it in ViewDidLoad like `checkBoxesCount = 0;`

Than Update your method like below

```
-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblvie];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblvie indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];


    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        checkBoxesCount = checkBoxesCount - 1;
        self.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count %d",checkBoxesCount];

           }
    else {
        [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
//                self.titleLabel.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
        checkBoxesCount = checkBoxesCount + 1;
        self.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count %d",checkBoxesCount];

    }
    [self.tblvie reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

Problem resolved. I tested same on my end.